# WPF RenderTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, rendertransform

I am drawing an `Ellipse` in the center of a `Canvas`.  When doing so the top left corner of the `Ellipse` is actually drawn in the center but I want the center point of the `Ellipse` to be in the center.  For this I presume I need a `RenderTransform` but I cannot get it working correctly.

```
<Ellipse Stroke="Red" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100">
```

Am I missing an attribute?

Comment: I think you should set attach property on canvas.Left and Canvas.top.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result using a converter:

**Xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:GetCentreConverter x:Key="CentreConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Ellipse Stroke="Red"
             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
             StrokeThickness="5"
             Width="100"
             Height="100"
             Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=canvas, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource CentreConverter}, ConverterParameter=50}"
             Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=canvas, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource CentreConverter}, ConverterParameter=50}"/>
</Canvas>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class GetCentreConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var width = double.Parse(value.ToString());
        var offset = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        return width/2 - offset;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cannot do this through attached properties unless you bind through viewModel which knows the exact center. You will need to use code behind to find out the center of canvas. Like:

```
myCanvas.SetLeft(elipse, (myCanvas.ActualWidth - elipse.ActualWidth) / 2);
myCanvas.SetTop(elipse, (myCanvas.ActualHeight - elipse.ActualHeight) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Grid` instead of `Canvas` as the container of the ellipse. So with

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

you will get your ellipse in the center of the `Grid` positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Canvas.Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left.aspx) and [Canvas.Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top.aspx) attached properties, as Vidas stated.

In addition to doing it in the code-behind, you could also write a custom converter so you could do it in XAML. For instance, if you write a DivideByTwoConverter, you could then bind the attached properties to the Width and Height of the Canvas and use the converter on the bindings.

I'm sure there are some other tricks to do the same.